# When to specify elements for classes?

Tags: css

```
/*INPUT BOXES ( input )
*/


.toggle_border_show{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.toggle_border_obscure{
  border: 1px solid #888888;
}
.toggle_border_hide{
  border: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

I noticed that these classes are only used on input elements.

Should I have pre-fixed them with input as such

```
/*INPUT BOXES ( input )
*/


input.toggle_border_show{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
input.toggle_border_obscure{
  border: 1px solid #888888;
}
input.toggle_border_hide{
  border: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the classes are only used on input elements then it is unnecessary to add the input before the class name.

Furthermore - as @PaulD.Waite mentioned in the comments - even if you plan on using these classes on other elements: if you are happy for these styles to apply to them as well - then input should still not be used before the class name.

Comment: +1 The rule I follow is: Be as specific as you need to be, and no more

Comment: how would I change the syntax to get rid of the element in this case - `p:hover.single_tag`

Comment: would it be - just `hover.single_tag`

Comment: @employee-0: I don’t think `p:hover.single_tag` will work anyway, as the pseudo-class (`:hover`) should come last. The version without specifying a tag would be `.single_tag:hover`.

Comment: @Danield: it’s also unnecessary to add the `input` if the author is happy for these styles to apply to any element to which the class is applied.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I edited my answer to include your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to specify the tag, but only the class according to [Google - Optimize browser rendering](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering?hl=fr#UseEfficientCSSSelectors).

> Remove redundant qualifiers. 
> These qualifiers are redundant: 
> ID
>   selectors qualified by class and/or tag selectors 
> **Class selectors
>   qualified by tag selectors 
> (when a class is only used for one tag,
>   which is a good design practice anyway)**.

Also, If you run a test with [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), you will get a warning if you use tag + class selectors.

Comment: can you provide a reference?

Comment: Selector performance is greatly exaggerated due to unrealistic benchmarks:  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: @Simon - where in you link does it talk about selectors?

Comment: It doesn't talk about selectors in the link, but if you add the extension Google Page Speed and try both scenarios, you will notice a warning saying: "Remove unnecessary selectors" with the input scenario.